# For loop to catenate files with two variables

Tags: cat, for, bioinformatics

I am relatively new to Linux in general and I hope someone can help me.

I would like to merge fastq.gz files from 4 different sequencing lanes. Each file has the following name: `GC082_F4.lane1.1901.R1.fastq.gz` with `GC082_F4` the name of the sample, `laneX` referring to the lane (1 to 4) and `R1` refers to the forward or reverse read ("R1" is reverse, "R2" is forward).

I want to concatenate the files from the 4 different lanes for each sample and this for the forward read (R1) and the reverse read (R2) separately.
So for this specific sample that would be:

For the forward reads:

```
cat GC082_F4.lane1.1901.R1.fastq.gz \
  GC082_F4.lane2.1901.R1.fastq.gz GC082_F4.lane3.1901.R1.fastq.gz \
  GC082_F4.lane4.1901.R1.fastq.gz > GC082_F4.R1.fastq.gz
```

For the reverse reads:

```
cat GC082_F4.lane1.1901.R2.fastq.gz \
  GC082_F4.lane2.1901.R2.fastq.gz GC082_F4.lane3.1901.R2.fastq.gz \
  GC082_F4.lane4.1901.R2.fastq.gz > GC082_F4.R2.fastq.gz
```

But since I have to do this for +100 samples, I was wondering whether I could use one single loop for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For clarity: is `GC082_F4` (the sample name) the variable you need to iterate over 100+ times? Where do the sample names come from? (A text file? A list you are manually typing? ...). Are the lanes going to be exactly "lane1", "lane2", "lane3" and "lane4" for every sample?

Comment: You can't just concatenate .gz files. They contain cumulative compression data which will differ for each file, but there is no compound structure provided by gzip. You can  append each .gz to a tar file, which does have such a structure.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant You _can_ concatenate `.gz` files. Uncompressing the concatenated file would result in a file which is the concatenation of the original uncompressed files.

Comment: @fra-san Yes, I have +100 samples with different sample names (eg. GC083_H07, GC082_A05 etc.). The sample name (and thus the file name) is actually much longer, but this is the part that is different for each file (apart from the lane number and R1/R2). These are the files I received from an external provider so I don't have a text file of all samples/file names, but I could make one if necessary.  Yes, for every sample the lanes have the same name "lane1", "lane2", etc.

Comment: For a useful answer, please provide one _full_ filename. It it correct to say that the relevant parts of the filename are separated by `.`, i.e. you don't need to split in addition at, say, the `_` in `GC082_F4` or similar for purposes of grouping into one cumulative file?

Comment: @Kusalananda True (in a narrow sense), but useless for purpose. The --list option only shows the last file (name and size). When you decompress, there is no naming, and no demarcation between the files. I suspect the OP is expecting gzip to be GNU/zip, and (as it is not) this becomes an XY problem.

Comment: This is an example of the complete filename: GC082_F10.1903_Clonal_microbial_sequencing.130.NextSeq.FB.lane1.gcap_19_01.R1.fastq.gz. But only the parts "GC082_F10","lane1" and "R1" change for each file. The name of the output file does not really matter, as long as the sample name ("GC082_F10") and the read ("R1") is mentioned.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you have the complete set of files at once, or will further files appear (in batches or in real-time) that require to be appended to their appropriate  target?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant there is no need for a demarcation between the files nor is there any need to recover the original files. The OP doesn't mention any of this, but those files contain DNA sequences, simple ASCII, so all you need is the raw data.

Comment: I have an innate aversion to discarding data that might be significant. When somebody finds a run of invalid data, they want to fix the mechanism. They ask "Which lane, which file, which date, which sample?" you have to say "Sorry, we threw that away because we didn't think anybody would care".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply identify the unique parts of the file and cat those:

```
cat GC082_F4.*.R1.fastq.gz > GC082_F4_R1.fastq.gz
cat GC082_F4.*.R2.fastq.gz > GC082_F4_R2.fastq.gz
```

So, if you have multiple samples, you can do:

```
for sample in GC082_F4 GC083_F4 GC084_F4 GC085_F4 ... GC0NN_F4; do
    cat "$sample".*.R1.fastq.gz > "$sample"_R1.fastq.gz
    cat "$sample".*.R2.fastq.gz > "$sample"_R2.fastq.gz
done
```

You can also provide a list of sample names as input:

```
while read sample; do
    cat "$sample".*.R1.fastq.gz > "$sample"_R1.fastq.gz
    cat "$sample".*.R2.fastq.gz > "$sample"_R2.fastq.gz
done < sample.names.txt
```

Comment: Assuming the order of the files is relevant, it may be worth mentioning that the way the shell sorts the generated file names is locale-dependent. E.g. with `LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8`, "lane10.gz" sorts before "lane1.gz". The other way round with `LC_COLLATE=C`.